# Is it possible for a server running on Google App Engine to receive an RTSP stream?

Tags: google-app-engine, rtsp

Is it possible for a server running on Google App Engine to receive an RTSP stream?

If so, how easy is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

1. [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) is only a control protocol, the streaming part (delivery of media data) is done via [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol), which is UDP based protocol and hence not supported on App Engine.
2. RTSP itself has a similar format to HTTP so you *could* implement it on GAE. For example in Java you would extend GenericServlet and handle custom RTSP verbs.

So, you *could possibly* do the control part but not the media delivery.

Comment: I see, so if I'm trying to stream a video to GAE, that's not going to work?

Comment: No, receiving or sending a stream requires using RTP protocol, which is built on top of UDP and can not be implemented on GAE.